Why are Jesus and Satan both referred to as the morning star?
Why is Satan referred to as the morning star in Isaiah 14:12, and Jesus is also referred to as the morning star in Revelation 22:16?

There are several matters here that I will take quite separately.
Isaiah 14:12

Satan is not mentioned in this verse - the reference is to "the King of Babylon", V4.  However, a common interpretation of Isa 14:12 and the next few verses is that the taunt-song against the king of Babylon is that he represents Satan
There is no phrase in the Hebrew that says "Morning Star".  The actual phrase is הֵילֵ֣ל בֶּן־שָׁ֑חַר (helel ben shakar) = "Venus son of morning".


That is the noun "helel" (used only here in Isa 14:12) means "shining one", and was the usual name for what we now call Venus, the second-most inner planet of our solar system.
In the LXX this becomes ὁ ἑωσφόρος ὁ πρωὶ ἀνατέλλων (ho heosphoros ho proi anatellon) = "the Venus the early rising"
In the Latin this becomes, Lucifer, qui mane oriebaris = "Venus who rose in the morning"

Note that the word "star" is absent completely.  Further, the three names "Helel" (Hebrew), "Heosphoros" (Greek), "Lucifer" (Latin) all mean the same thing - what we call "Venus" in English.
However, various English versions translate this word as either:

morning star
evening star
day star
Lucifer (ie, leaving the Latin untranslated)
... but all mean the same thing - "Venus".

Rev 22:16
In Rev 22:16 we have the Greek:

ὁ ἀστὴρ ὁ λαμπρός, ὁ πρωϊνός = The star, the radiant, the morning"
(very literally)

This is very different from Isa 14:12. Rev 22:16 offers a series of titles for Jesus:

the root and offspring of David
the radiant (="bright")
the star
the morning

These titles are all unique to Jesus.  We also see the title, "Morning Star" for Jesus in 2 Peter 1:19, Rev 2:28.

I might raise an eyebrow here. I don't see anything in the Hebrew that necessitates "helel" meaning Venus.  The translators of the LXX seem to figure this "helel" to be a none other than Venus, the morning star, εωσφορος (eosphoros). The Pulpit Commentary notes: The word translated "Lucifer" means properly "shining one," and no doubt here designates a star; but whether any particular star or no is uncertain.

The word lucifer appears several times in the Latin Vulgate.  It is capitalized as a name for this verse and was indeed what was used to identify Venus.

Why do no English versions translate it "Venus"?

@Nacht - good question - I do not know but they probably use the more common English names as listed above.

In the transliteration from the LXX you left out “o proi”.

@DaG - many thanks for pointimng that out.  Now fixed.

Satan the Morning Star (Isaiah 14:12):
For starters, the Hebrew word “helel” means something along the lines of “a shining one” “light bearer,” or “morning star.”
It may be associated with the planet Venus.

(12) How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer, son of the morning!—The word for Lucifer is, literally, the shining one, the
planet Venus, the morning star, the son of the dawn, as the symbol of
the Babylonian power, which was so closely identified with astrolatry.
“Lucifer” etymologically gives the same meaning, and is used by Latin
poets (Tibull. i., 10, 62) for Venus, as an equivalent for the
phôsphoros of the Greeks. (Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers)

Venus appears as a bright star in the morning.
“morning star” (or “Lucifer”) is used to describe the fall of the Babylonian king. Likewise, we know Satan fell from grace, however it may not refer to Satan at all.

Some enthusiasts believe that Isaiah was really talking about satan,
but no, he wasn't. The prophet Ezekiel wrote a similar taunt, but
addressed to the king of Tyre this time: "You had the seal of
perfection. Full of wisdom and perfect in beauty, you were in Eden, in
the garden of God" (Ezekiel 28:12-13). The key to all this is that
these prophets lamented the once greatness and righteousness of
Babylon and Tyre, which they wasted on their desires to be powerful
and wealthy. (Abarim Publications)


Verse 12. - How art thou fallen from heaven, O Lucifer! Babylon's
sudden fall is compared, with great force and beauty, to the (seeming)
fall of a star from heaven. The word translated "Lucifer" means
properly "shining one," and no doubt here designates a star; but
whether any particular star or no is uncertain. (Pulpit Commentary)

Jesus the Morning Star (Revelation 22:16):
Jesus refers to Himself as the “bright morning star.”

Just as the morning star appears before the sun rises, so Jesus will
come for the church before he returns to restore Israel to himself. (bibleref)

Jesus has the role as the light that brings hope and salvation to humanity.

This is Christ’s interpretation of His own earlier utterance where He
calls himself “the morning star”, but here He features the
characteristic brightness of that star. As the bright morning star, He
is explicitly the brightest star in the whole galaxy. He is the one
whose1 return will remove the cold and dark hour before the sunrise and
bring in the perfect day of God (Moffatt, Beckwith). (blessedhope)


The morning star has ever been proverbial for brightness and beauty,
and, as the harbinger of the day, is the bringer of light, life, and
joy. Moreover, a star is often a sign of royalty: "There shall come a
star out of Jacob, and a sceptre shall rise out of Israel" (Numbers
24:17); and as such it appeared to the Wise Men (Matthew 2:2). (Pulpit Commentary)

Jesus’ reference as the morning star illuminates His divine glory, his role as the bringer of the brightest light and hope.

1 - fixed spelling.

Back in ancient times, the Morning Star would refer to an astronomical body (planet or star) which would appear early in the morning, before the dawn, before the sun rises, signalling that the sun is not far behind, and so the night is almost over.
Satan (aka Lucifer - literally the morning star, bringer of light) is referred to as the morning star in Isaiah as he was supposed to be an angel, a servant of God, reflecting the light of God (the glory of God) to all creation. However, he fell, Satan did the opposite of what he was supposed to do and rebelled against God, bringing darkness (sin) into creation, and so as Isaiah says, Satan is cast out of heaven and down to the earth, and so is no longer the morning star. Jesus himself refers to this event in Luke 10:18, "I saw Satan fall like lightning from heaven." (NIV)
Jesus refers to himself as the morning star as he signals the darkness is coming to an end. Jesus became flesh, was crucified, died, buried, resurrected, and ascended into heaven, and so he has gone on ahead of us, signalling that the night, the darkness of this world (sin) is not permanent, but that the light, the glory of God in all its fullness, is on its way.

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE plebbus. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out what we are looking for in answers and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality answers. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Hi plebbus, welcome to BH.SE - thanks for contributing! Appreciate that you're suggesting that Venus is the Morning Star. It would be helpful to provide some kind of source affirming that this would also be the case for ancient references to 'the morning star', or whether this is just an assumption we're importing from modern times.

Thanks for spotting the assumption!  I've removed the reference to Venus as, reading around, it's clear that ancient cultures also considered bodies such as Sirius and Mercury as the "morning star" (as well as Venus).

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
